# Concatenate sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 without converting to PCL and back?

Tags: ros, pcl, ros-noetic, pcl-ros

For example, there is this
[Merging 2 pcl from kinects](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/58569/merging-2-pcl-from-kinects)

Where the OP converts to/from PCL objects.

Unless this kind of thing is a shallow copy, I have a hard time believing there isn't a concatenate for the ros message type directly.  Specifically asking about ROS1

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

You can concatenate them easily. Assuming all of your point clouds are in the same frame, please use `std::memcpy` on the `cloud_out.data` vector. See below a complete function:

```
inline void MergePC::combinePointClouds(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& cloud1,
                                        const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& cloud2,
                                        const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& cloud3,
                                        sensor_msgs::PointCloud2& cloud_out)
{
  // assign cloud 1 to output cloud
  cloud_out = cloud1;

  // get the lengths of each cloud
  size_t cloud1_len = cloud1.data.size();
  size_t cloud2_len = cloud2.data.size();
  size_t cloud3_len = cloud3.data.size();

  // set the parameters of output cloud
  cloud_out.height = 1;
  cloud_out.width = cloud1.width * cloud1.height +
                    cloud2.width * cloud2.height + cloud3.width * cloud3.height;

  cloud_out.is_dense =
      (!cloud1.is_dense || !cloud2.is_dense || !cloud3.is_dense) ? false : true;

  // reserve the memory
  cloud_out.data.resize(cloud1_len + cloud2_len + cloud3_len);

  // copy cloud 2 to output cloud
  std::memcpy(&cloud_out.data[cloud1_len], &cloud2.data[0], cloud2_len);

  // copy cloud 3 to output cloud
  std::memcpy(&cloud_out.data[cloud1_len + cloud2_len], &cloud3.data[0],
              cloud3_len);
}
```

Feel free to checkout a working node [here](https://github.com/ravijo/multiple_kinect_baxter_calibration/blob/5b883da744799abbf78f400f40e142d8450a7c9d/src/merge_pc.cpp).